# Find corresponding raster values for points table

Tags: postgis

In my PostgreSQL database there is a raster table and a point table with the same projections. The point table has colums such as id, address and geom. The raster table has columns such as id, r_proj4 and rast. Each line of the raster table describes one raster tile. 
How can I retrieve the raster value for each point?

I expect rough guidelines how  to solve this problem and PostGIS code examples.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of query I use a combination of `ST_Intersects` with [`ST_Value`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html). An example is below.

```sql
SELECT p.gid, 
       ST_Value(r.rast, p.geom) 
  FROM points_table p,
       raster_table r
 WHERE ST_Intersects(r.rast, s.geom)
```

Answer (score -1):

Right off the top of my head, I would say that [`st_intersection()`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Intersection.html) may get you rasters encompassing geometry points of interest (if that's what you're looking for). You can use it as a criteria, while inner-joining both of your tables, like that:

```
select p1.*, r1.rast
from points p1
join rasters r1
on (st_intersection(r1.rast, p1.geom)).geom = p1.geom
```

Comment: This query does not return the raster value at the points.